# Export without destructuring

Tags: javascript

```
import { utils } from 'shared'

const {
  pick,
  get,
  isEmpty,
  sortBy,
  orderObjectsArray,
  isString
} = utils.lodashAlternative

export { pick, get, isEmpty, sortBy, orderObjectsArray, isString }
```

Above you can see exports , imagine I don't want to desctructure all of those functions , how can I do it ? I've tried to make `export utils.lodashAlternative` , but it will not work , also :

```
const {...data} = utils.lodashAlternative

export {...data}
```

Also will not work, it there any way to export it without discructuring ?

Comment: Do you want to export everything from `utils.lodashAlternative`?

Comment: yes, everything @VLAZ

Comment: [MDN - Re-exporting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#re-exporting_aggregating)

Comment: I don't see solution there ) could you attach how should I do it in my case @Yousaf

Comment: Do you want to export each function in `utils.lodashAlternative` as a named export? I think re-exporting each function as a named export is no better than what you are already doing.

Comment: I want to export every function that utils.lodashAlternative holds , I don't want to go in file, and export new function each time @Yousaf

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to export everything under utils.lodashAlternative is creating an alias and exporting that one instead.
There's no need to create an object and spread lodashAlternative inside.

**You can't declare and export afterwards (unless you use as)!**

Way 1: using `default`

```js
import { utils } from 'shared'

const lodashAlternative = utils.lodashAlternative;

export default lodashAlternative;
```

Way 2: exporting directly

```js
import { utils } from 'shared'

export const lodashAlternative = utils.lodashAlternative;
```

Way 3: export each one separately, to be able to import them separately

```js
import {utils} from "shared";

const { foo, bar } = utils.lodashAlternative;

export { foo, bar };
```

import then:

```js
// WITH WAY 1
import lodashAlternative from "lodash-alternative";

// WITH WAY 2
import {lodashAlternative} from "lodash-alternative";

// WITH WAY 3
import {foo, bar} from "lodash-alternative";
```

[Blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-as6vu6)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: answer is wrong , it will no work , what difference then between my code export utils.lodashAlternative and your, you just assign it to additional variable ?)

Comment: It works. If it doesn't work you have some issues with your code or bundler.
Give me a sec, I'm preparing a blitz.
The difference with your's is just that my code has a better performance...

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich check now! You have 2 ways, you can't do `export foo` after declaring it!

Comment: You can't do that, unless you destructure...you can only in Typescript. Not in plain JS. Sorry pal!

Comment: @OtaconKiko, yes thanks , this is what I wanted to know , is there any other way to make it easier , as I see there is no way